# "changed by" on nodes

Tags: 7, users, nodes

```
mysql> select nid, uid, created, changed from node;
+-----+-----+------------+------------+
| nid | uid | created    | changed    |
+-----+-----+------------+------------+
|   1 |   8 | 1336040166 | 1336046390 |
+-----+-----+------------+------------+
```

I'd like to have an "changed by" column on the `node` table, exactly as we have a "created by" (the uid field). This would keep track of who made the last change on that node. I know that this could be derived from the `node_revision` table but this depends on the revisions being enabled for the content types I'm interested.

So, what is the best way to do this? And why doesn't Drupal core offer this by default? I thought that "changed by" is a pretty standard piece of information that a CMS should attach to content.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't enable revisioning?  Seems like the easiest way to get what you need.  It's probably what I'd do.  If people are going to be editing nodes frequently, it also means you have a backup of previous versions.

Comment: Yes I can. I'd like to know if it's possible to have it on the main `node` table though. It looks more straightforward.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I thought this would be quite tough to do, but as it turns out it's fairly easy.

You just need to create a custom module that adds a column to the node table on install, implement [`hook_schema_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_schema_alter/7) so Drupal knows about the new column, and add some logic to provide a value before the node is saved.

Here's a small module that will do the trick:

File: node_table_alter.info

```
name = Node Table Alter
core = 7.x
```

File: node_table_alter.install

```
function node_table_alter_install() {
  // Add the new field to the node table
  $field = array(
    'description' => 'Stores the user id of the last user to alter the node',
    'type' => 'int',
    'unsigned' => TRUE
  );

  db_add_field('node', 'changed_by', $field);
}
```

File: node_table_alter.module

```
function node_table_alter_schema_alter(&$schema) {
  // Add the new field to the schema cache
  $schema['node']['fields']['changed_by'] = array(
    'description' => 'Stores the user id of the last user to alter the node',
    'type' => 'int',
    'unsigned' => TRUE
  );
}

function node_table_alter_node_presave($node) {
  // Populate the changed_by column with current user's id
  $node->changed_by = $GLOBALS['user']->uid;
}
```

You may want to add logic to remove the field again on uninstall, and add an index to the table for the `changed_by` column (see [`db_add_index()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_add_index/7)), but this should give you a good place to start.

The beauty of this method is that you have effectively added a new property to the node. You'll be able to use `node_load()`, `EntityFieldQuery`s, etc. with it as if it were any of the other standard properties for a node.

God bless Drupal for being so extendable!

Comment: BTW you can use exactly the same logic to answer [your other question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30086/custom-node-status).

Comment: For complete entity integration, and if your are using the Entity API module, you will also need to implement hook_entity_property_info() to pvoide informatiom about this new property.

Comment: @PierreBuyle Good point, didn't think of that

Comment: This is exactly what the UUID module does. Check it out for a more complete implementation of something similar. http://drupal.org/project/uuid

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation and clean solution!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could add a entity reference field (let's call it `field_changed_by_user`) to the content type you need to track. Then you could use `hook_node_presave` to save the user id to the node like this:

```
function hook_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node->nid && $node->type == 'content_type_to_track_changes_for') {
    global $user;
    $node->field_changed_by_user['und'][0]['target_id'] = $user->uid;
  }
}
```

I think it's also possible to update the field with the user's id just by creating a rule. You can read more [here](http://drupal.org/project/rules).