# How to change Views field settings programmatically?

Tags: 7, views, media

**I would like to change some field settings in a given view** created with [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) **programmatically**.

For example, I would like to change the "***Formatter***" and "***Image style***" settings of an *Image field*. This is what the settings of this field look like when I export this view:

```
/* Field: Taxonomy term: Natural images */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_natural_images']['id'] = 'field_gallery_natural_images';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_natural_images']['table'] = 'field_data_field_gallery_natural_images';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_natural_images']['field'] = 'field_gallery_natural_images';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_natural_images']['click_sort_column'] = 'fid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_natural_images']['type'] = 'colorbox';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_natural_images']['settings'] = array(
  'colorbox_node_style' => '',
  'colorbox_image_style' => '',
  'colorbox_gallery' => 'post',
  'colorbox_gallery_custom' => '',
  'colorbox_caption' => 'auto',
  'colorbox_caption_custom' => '',
  'display_empty' => '',
  'custom_text' => '',
  'empty_callback' => 'mymodule_empty_fields_no_data',
);
```

I would like to change the "Image style" of the Colorbox formatter somehow like this:

```
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_natural_images']['settings']['colorbox_node_style'] = 'thumbnail';
```

and save that. How should I do that?

Like here:

[image: Views - change Image field settings]

---

## EDIT 1.

Maybe I should use `views_save_view()`:
http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_save_view/7

It saves a view - so maybe I should query the whole view, change that, and use this function. But how exactly?

## EDIT 2.

I found in `views/includes/admin.inc` that the given view gets saved like this: `$form_state['view']->save();` in `views_ui_edit_view_form_submit()`.

I already know [how to change "Image style" of an Image field in a given view mode programmatically (as on "Manage display" tab after clicking the gear)](http://drupal.org/project/views), but now I would be happy if I could do something similar with a given view.

Comment: try changing it in on of [the hooks](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21views%21views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7), i'd suggest [hook_views_pre_build](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_build/7)

Comment: Just FYI. You blacked out your taxonomy term in the photo; but it's in the code dump you provided.

Comment: @mojzis: thanks, but as far as I know, it just changes the **display** of the given view, but it doesn't actually **save** these changes in the database. So I would like to save the changes the same way I do it via the Views UI, but programmatically.

Comment: @chrisjlee: yes, thanks, I know that, but later I realized it doesn't really matter. :)

Comment: I Expect an answer from @Clive here.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to save changes to the view programmatically instead og using the default or default_alter hook to define/alter the view like you want it?

Comment: @googletorp: as I wrote [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49398/how-to-change-views-field-settings-programmatically/49583#comment51325_49583), views created via the Views UI (which are not stored in code, only in database) can not be overridden this way. Is this answer satisfying to you? :)

Comment: @sk8erPeter If you use the UI to create the view, you can use features to export it to code. Even views itself can export views. So why not use this?

Comment: @googletorp: and what if I export these views? Why would it be better? OK, my views would be stored in code, not in the database, this is cool. I can also override them in another module with `hook_views_default_views_alter()` and other hooks without overriding them via the Views UI. BUT right after overriding them, as far as I know, the view gets "cloned" in the database, and gets overridden with the new settings. MAYBE this way I can still use the mentioned hooks, dunno. But what if I've created 10-20 views via the Views UI? Should I export these, delete the original, put in module, etc.?

Comment: @googletorp: continuing the previous: I don't understand why exporting would be more comfortable than having to mess with exporting 20-30 views created via Views UI, putting it in code, deleting the previous ones (created via the UI), enabling the new ones (which are already in code). It STILL doesn't change my need to programmatically change the OVERRIDDEN views' field settings. By the way, why couldn't I be interested? I don't understand what your problem is with asking this question, which could be interesting for others too. :)

Comment: @Sk8erPeter I don't have a problem with the question - but I find the method inferior compared to doing a single export with features and then doing. `$ drush fu-all` `$ drush fr-all`. I think you are doing it the wrong way - but you are free to do it whichever way you want to.

Comment: @googletorp: so do you think that everyone is doing it the wrong way, who wants to manage and override his/her views via the Views UI, and doesn't export all of them? Really? I just wanted to do the same like managing these settings via the Views UI, but temporarily doing it programmatically (original reason: on the shared host, I ran out of memory when trying to edit image fields which are set to ColorBox display in a view, dunno why - and I wanted to know this method just because of curiosity, too).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**UPDATED**:

You can use this code snippet to change a view without `views_alter`:

```
$view = views_get_view($view_name, TRUE);
$view->display['default']->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_natural_images']['settings']['colorbox_node_style'] = 'thumbnail';
views_save_view($view);
```

Change `default` display ID if you want to use display other than the default.

---

If you have exported the view to code using `hook_views_default_views()` or the Features module, there is a hook to alter the views programmatically:

```
/**
 * Alter default views defined by other modules.
 *
 * This hook is called right before all default views are cached to the
 * database. It takes a keyed array of views by reference.
 *
 * Example usage to add a field to a view:
 * @code
 *   $handler =& $view->display['DISPLAY_ID']->handler;
 *   // Add the user name field to the view.
 *   $handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
 *   $handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
 *   $handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
 *   $handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = 'Author';
 *   $handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['link_to_user'] = 1;
 * @endcode
 */
function hook_views_default_views_alter(&$views) {
  if (isset($views['taxonomy_term'])) {
    $views['taxonomy_term']->display['default']->display_options['title'] = 'Categories';
  }
}
```

For example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_default_views_alter()
 */
function MYMODULE_views_default_views_alter(&$views) {
  if (isset($views['VIEW_NAME'])) {
    $views['VIEW_NAME']->display['default']->display_options['fields']['field_gallery_natural_images']['settings']['colorbox_node_style'] = 'thumbnail';
  }
}
```

Remember to clear the cache and do revert of the view to apply changes.

Comment: thanks, but `hook_views_default_views_alter()` is just for altering _"default views defined by other modules"_, which means views created (or even overridden?) via the Views UI (which are only saved to the database) can not be changed this way, only the views defined in code, but now my purpose is to alter some particular views created via Views UI without exporting them. :-( Any other ideas?

Comment: For the fields to be displayed on the Views UI, in `views_ui_edit_form_get_bucket()`, fields are getting added and linked to `admin/structure/views/nojs/config-item/$view->name/$display->id/$type/$id`, and can be changed, maybe I should go this way, and trace this one... I started it, but still didn't find the real solution.

Comment: @Sk8erPeter I updated the answer with an alternative solution.

Comment: wow, using `views_get_view()`, changing the appropriate display settings, and after that, saving the view with `views_save_view()` really solved it! Thank you very much, **smartinm**! :) You deserve the kudos. :) I also upvoted your answer for your efforts. I tested it this way: http://pastebin.com/ukSy0xqM, and it really worked.

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help you :)

Comment: This was really helpful.

Comment: (Here's what I meant to say...) **for adding a column before the last existing one** you need to splice it in to the existing `$view->display['default']->display_options['fields']` field. You can't simply use `array_splice` because it will reset your new field array key to 0.(See [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php#5674) .)

Comment: Holy crap this was awesome. You can also use unset(); to remove elements from the view before you save.